# hiddens fields in web form give error in php post

Tags: hidden-field

hiddens fields below in web form give error in php post, all other fields are ok
only hiddens although all have values as checked in chrome, well?

Notice: Undefined index: catHidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: carIdHidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: location in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: location2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined index: subTotal in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined index: FinalAmount in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined index: S1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: S2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: S3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined index: GPS in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 39

Notice: Undefined index: daysHidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 47

Notice: Undefined index: discount in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: rate in C:\xampp\htdocs\VPS\PphCHnew\paypal\noPayPal.php on line 59
Unable to execute query. Please try again later.565

Comment: are just below form tag

Comment: solved forgot name attr